# CCNet web dashboard scripts being passed as text/plain

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

My web dashboard for cruisecontrol.net seems to be rendering incorrectly.  I am getting mostly java-script errors and I'm unsure why this is happening.

Most of the errors are like this:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.
```

There are other errors present but I believe this is caused by the scripts being interpreted incorrectly.  Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a configuration error with IIS.  The static content role service had not been installed.  After doing so MIME types are now being delivered correctly.